# AJAX fires success twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Javascript code. For some reason the ajax success option fires twice, I get two identical alerts.

```
if (message =="") {
    $.ajax({
        url:  '/dev/php/register.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {firstname:voornaam,lastname:achternaam,email:email,password:wachtwoord,gender:gender,date:datum},
        success: alert("Account aangemaakt")
        })
}
else {
        showSnackBar(message);
        return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its calling the alert function when it is being set up and again when success is fired. try

```
success: function(data){
    alert("Account aangemaakt");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change a thing

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by renaming the function to something random like wowwat. I don't know why this works.

```
    if (message =="") {
    $.ajax({
        url:  '/dev/php/register.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {firstname:voornaam,lastname:achternaam,email:email,password:wachtwoord,gender:gender,date:datum},
        success: function(wowwat)
        { 
            alert("Account aangemaakt");
        }
})
}
else {
        showSnackBar(message);
        return false;
     }
```